# Showing The Output Of Statement In BalloonTipText In NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this statement:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select name,lname from table1 where column1='" + x + "'");
```

I want to show the output of it in BalloonTipText in NotifyIcon, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (rdr.Read())
  {
    sb.AppendLine(rdr["name"].ToString() + ' ' + rdr["lname"].ToString());
  }
}

notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = sb.ToString();
notifyIcon.ShowBallonTip(30000);
```

Comment: thanks,i dont know how to use datareader and i cant use executescalar because my output is name,lname,i think i should google how to use datareader

Comment: thanks,now i want to know if i have two records in name and lname how should i show them??for example in ballontiptext i want to show:alex a,fred b

Comment: solved with your help,thanks,just a point is that in your code its rdr["name"] and rdr["lname"],thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

from [The MS notifyicon page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx), do you need to know how to execute the sql command also?

```
 this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);

        // The Icon property sets the icon that will appear
        // in the systray for this application.
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("appicon.ico");

        // The ContextMenu property sets the menu that will
        // appear when the systray icon is right clicked.
        notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = this.contextMenu1;

        // The Text property sets the text that will be displayed,
        // in a tooltip, when the mouse hovers over the systray icon.
        notifyIcon1.Text = SqlCommandResultsHere;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;

        // Handle the DoubleClick event to activate the form.
        notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);
```